# Join an array object and string variable in javascript or angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello i am trying to add an array and a variable and a "." in between them. `data` is the object i get from json. And `valuePickup` is a variable.

I am using this

```
self.GetIndex = function (valuePickup) {
    $http.get("someURL").success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data + "." + valuePickup); //It is not resulting the object
        console.log(data.categories); // this is how i want the above line looks like.
    });
}
```

It looks something like this. and what i get in return in `[object Object].categories`

Is there any way to join an array object and a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access property by variable key:

```
console.log(data[valuePickup]);
```